РЕБ банястий, банчастий, баньовий чи баневий?
Зараз багато розмов про купольніросіянізм? РЕБи. Передивився декілька словників і бачу

Ку́польный – баньови́й.
Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) 


Купольный – баньови́й;

к. (в виде купола) – банча́стий.
Свод – склепі́ння;
с. купольный – с. баня́сте;
Фонарь – ліхта́р (-ря́);
ф. купольный – л. баньови́й;
Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський) 



карка́с 1. ришту́нок,-нка, карка́с,-су (тримальна основа будь-якого виробу)
2. кістя́к,-ка́
к. ку́польный ришту́нок ба́невий
свод 1. зводі́ння; зве́дення; звід,-во́ду
2. склепі́ння (конструкція)
с. ку́польный склепі́ння ба́неве
Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш) 

Як же правильно?

Це єдиний 9-баневий дерев’яний собор у світі. >>
Якщо Софія Константинопольська – банева  базиліка, то Софія Київська – хрестово-баневий храм, що склався у Візантії до часів хрещення Русі. >>
П’ятинефний багатокупольний хрещато-баневий храм із розкішним, прикрашеним дорогоцінними мозаїками та стінописом інтер’єром збудували на замовлення князя Ярослава Мудрого як символ величі Русі. >>
1896–1911 на тер. монастиря зведено 13-баневий Свято-Миколаївський собор (архіт. В.Ніколаєв, за ескізом вел. кн. Петра Миколайовича) – найбільший за об'ємом храм у Києві, з трьома вівтарями та цокольною церквою; для перекриття центр. частини собору використано унікальну конструкцію з двох перехрещених цегляних арок (у її проектуванні брав участь архіт. О.Вербицький). >>

Припущення
Можливо подібно до кулястий це має бути банястий, бо його покриття має форму бані. З іншого боку, не сам РЕБ має форму бані, а лише його покриття.

КУЛЯ́СТИЙ а, е.
Який має форму кулі (див. ку́ля 1); круглий (у 1 знач.).
На тлі свіжого, як повесні, лісу показується біла мурована брама, з-за якої визирають кулясті чорні баньки церкви з золотими зірками. (М. Коцюбинський)


Як правильно - "бітний" чи "бітовий", "бітність" чи "бітовість"?

Я думаю, варто пояснити, що мається на увазі під купольним РЕБом. Хоча я, здається, уже знайшов. Але все одно — що нижче «поріг входження» (що менше додаткових [які не стосуються власне мови] знань треба мати читачу), то краще для запитання.

Здається, «якийсь РЕБ» — це в будь-якому разі сленговий чи принаймні розмовний вислів. Бо РЕБ — це ж формально вона («радіоелектронна боротьба»); формально — «якийсь засіб РЕБ» (чи «засіб якоїсь РЕБ»), а не «якийсь РЕБ». Тобто я не маю на увазі «не кажіть так», навпаки, я за найефективніший варіант, і колись, гадаю, «реб» таки внесуть у словники окремим словом, чоловічого роду (і малими літерами, а не як абревіатуру); але поки цього не відбулося.

@Sasha з того, що я бачу в мережі, то це слово і словосполучення вже набуло широкого вжитку.
